# python regex to capture a pattern which appear an unknown number of times

Tags: python, regex

For example:

```
import re
FOO = """neighbors= {5 7 9 11 13 14 15 16 17 }"""
COMPILE = re.compile('(neighbors\s*=\s*\{\s*(\d+\s*)+\})')
match = re.findall(COMPILE, FOO)
print match[0]
```

(the code is from here: [find a repetitive expression using python regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092863/find-a-repetitive-expression-using-python-regular-expression) )

This will only capture the last group, i.e. "17 ". What if I want to capture each of these groups, i.e. 
"5", "7", "9", ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a simpler regex to match all numbers, and using this in with `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = 'neighbors= {5 7 9 11 13 14 15 16 17 }'
r = re.compile('(\d+)')
print re.findall(r,s)
```

which outputs

```
Out[5]: ['5', '7', '9', '11', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17']
```

Comment: simpler than mine, if you don't need to check for the `name={…}`syntax

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you cannot use a single capturing group followed by a repetition marker `+` or `*` to capture an arbitrary number of sequences.

Maybe you should capture the sequence of integers and then split it, like this:

```
import re
FOO = """neighbors= {5 7 9 11 13 14 15 16 17 }"""
COMPILE = re.compile('(neighbors\s*=\s*\{\s*((\d+\s*)+)\})')  # added a capturing group
match = re.findall(COMPILE, FOO)
print match[0][1].split()
```

which prints:

```
['5', '7', '9', '11', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17']
```

Additionally, maybe you don't need to `findall` but only to `match`, like this:

```
import re
FOO = """neighbors= {5 7 9 11 13 14 15 16 17 }"""
COMPILE = re.compile('(neighbors\s*=\s*\{\s*((\d+\s*)+)\})')
match = re.match(COMPILE, FOO)
if match:
    print match.group(2).split()
else:
    print 'input does not match regex'
```

You can also take a look at the top answers of the following similar questions:

[python regex for repeating string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651870/python-regex-for-repeating-string)

[Python RegEx multiple groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963691/python-regex-multiple-groups)